# VK.COM embed set start time and hide controls

Tags: javascript, html, vk, vk-sdk

How can I embed a video from `vk.com` and specify the time on which the video should start (eg: the video should start from the middle, or from second 5), and to hide the controls, like on YouTube?

A simple embed looks like:

```
<iframe src="//vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=162756656&id=171388096&hash=b82cc24232fe7f9f&hd=2" width="853" height="480" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

To make it autoplay I solved by adding `&autoplay=1` at the end of the `src` url.

I tried to find an API or something else for the embed but I am unable to find it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like vk.com used to support `&t=1m14s` parameter when it was using Flash video player, but they don't have such functionality since they moved to HTML player.

So the answer is - there is no way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I will try using the flash video player, if it is available...

Answer (score 2):

To set a video's current time we use .currentTime  . In order to do this first you need the url of the actual video. To do so click into your iframe src then get the video src up to .mp4 which is https://cs634504.vk.me/u162756656/videos/6c35b838ac.480.mp4 .

```js
    var mediaElement =  document.getElementById("video");
 mediaElement.currentTime = 122;
```

```html
<video id="video" controls>
 <source src="https://cs634504.vk.me/u162756656/videos/6c35b838ac.480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Thank you! It is helpful, but is it legally to embed a video from a website by using the url of the video, not their embed code with their player (which has, usually, their logo, link to the video etc)?